# How to make "Laravel Localization To Vue/JSON" working

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I'm setting up the "Laravel Localization To Vue/JSON" in my Laravel 5.8. But when I'm trying to translate e. g.

```
{{ trans.get('Header') }}
```

it will only output "Header". The "Header" locale is set in messages.php under the used locale.

When I

```
console.log(messages)
```

or

```
console.log(messages.en.messages.Header)
```

it shows the correct translations for all languages.

```
console.log(Vue.prototype.trans)
```

shows also the correct data

```
{
  "locale": "en",
  "fallback": "en",
  "messages": {
    "en": {
      "auth": {
        "failed": "These credentials do not match our records.",
        "throttle": "Too many login attempts. Please try again in :seconds seconds."
      },
      "messages": {
        "Header": "These credentials do not match our records.",
        "No item found": "Nix gefunden"
      },
      "pagination": {
        "previous": "&laquo; Previous",
        "next": "Next &raquo;"
      },
      "passwords": {
        "password": "Passwords must be at least eight characters and match the confirmation.",
        "reset": "Your password has been reset!",
        "sent": "We have e-mailed your password reset link!",
        "token": "This password reset token is invalid.",
        "user": "We can't find a user with that e-mail address."
      },
      "validation": {
        "accepted": "The :attribute must be accepted.",
        "active_url": "The :attribute is not a valid URL.",
        "after": "The :attribute must be a date after :date.",
        "after_or_equal": "The :attribute must be a date after or equal to :date.",
        "alpha": "The :attribute may only contain letters.",
        "alpha_dash": "The :attribute may only contain letters, numbers, dashes and underscores.",
        "alpha_num": "The :attribute may only contain letters and numbers.",
        "array": "The :attribute must be an array.",
        "before": "The :attribute must be a date before :date.",
        "before_or_equal": "The :attribute must be a date before or equal to :date.",
        "between": {
          "numeric": "The :attribute must be between :min and :max.",
          "file": "The :attribute must be between :min and :max kilobytes.",
          "string": "The :attribute must be between :min and :max characters.",
          "array": "The :attribute must have between :min and :max items."
        },
        "boolean": "The :attribute field must be true or false.",
        "confirmed": "The :attribute confirmation does not match.",
        "date": "The :attribute is not a valid date.",
        "date_equals": "The :attribute must be a date equal to :date.",
        "date_format": "The :attribute does not match the format :format.",
        "different": "The :attribute and :other must be different.",
        "digits": "The :attribute must be :digits digits.",
        "digits_between": "The :attribute must be between :min and :max digits.",
        "dimensions": "The :attribute has invalid image dimensions.",
        "distinct": "The :attribute field has a duplicate value.",
        "email": "The :attribute must be a valid email address.",
        "ends_with": "The :attribute must end with one of the following: :values",
        "exists": "The selected :attribute is invalid.",
        "file": "The :attribute must be a file.",
        "filled": "The :attribute field must have a value.",
        "gt": {
          "numeric": "The :attribute must be greater than :value.",
          "file": "The :attribute must be greater than :value kilobytes.",
          "string": "The :attribute must be greater than :value characters.",
          "array": "The :attribute must have more than :value items."
        },
        "gte": {
          "numeric": "The :attribute must be greater than or equal :value.",
          "file": "The :attribute must be greater than or equal :value kilobytes.",
          "string": "The :attribute must be greater than or equal :value characters.",
          "array": "The :attribute must have :value items or more."
        },
        "image": "The :attribute must be an image.",
        "in": "The selected :attribute is invalid.",
        "in_array": "The :attribute field does not exist in :other.",
        "integer": "The :attribute must be an integer.",
        "ip": "The :attribute must be a valid IP address.",
        "ipv4": "The :attribute must be a valid IPv4 address.",
        "ipv6": "The :attribute must be a valid IPv6 address.",
        "json": "The :attribute must be a valid JSON string.",
        "lt": {
          "numeric": "The :attribute must be less than :value.",
          "file": "The :attribute must be less than :value kilobytes.",
          "string": "The :attribute must be less than :value characters.",
          "array": "The :attribute must have less than :value items."
        },
        "lte": {
          "numeric": "The :attribute must be less than or equal :value.",
          "file": "The :attribute must be less than or equal :value kilobytes.",
          "string": "The :attribute must be less than or equal :value characters.",
          "array": "The :attribute must not have more than :value items."
        },
        "max": {
          "numeric": "The :attribute may not be greater than :max.",
          "file": "The :attribute may not be greater than :max kilobytes.",
          "string": "The :attribute may not be greater than :max characters.",
          "array": "The :attribute may not have more than :max items."
        },
        "mimes": "The :attribute must be a file of type: :values.",
        "mimetypes": "The :attribute must be a file of type: :values.",
        "min": {
          "numeric": "The :attribute must be at least :min.",
          "file": "The :attribute must be at least :min kilobytes.",
          "string": "The :attribute must be at least :min characters.",
          "array": "The :attribute must have at least :min items."
        },
        "not_in": "The selected :attribute is invalid.",
        "not_regex": "The :attribute format is invalid.",
        "numeric": "The :attribute must be a number.",
        "present": "The :attribute field must be present.",
        "regex": "The :attribute format is invalid.",
        "required": "The :attribute field is required.",
        "required_if": "The :attribute field is required when :other is :value.",
        "required_unless": "The :attribute field is required unless :other is in :values.",
        "required_with": "The :attribute field is required when :values is present.",
        "required_with_all": "The :attribute field is required when :values are present.",
        "required_without": "The :attribute field is required when :values is not present.",
        "required_without_all": "The :attribute field is required when none of :values are present.",
        "same": "The :attribute and :other must match.",
        "size": {
          "numeric": "The :attribute must be :size.",
          "file": "The :attribute must be :size kilobytes.",
          "string": "The :attribute must be :size characters.",
          "array": "The :attribute must contain :size items."
        },
        "starts_with": "The :attribute must start with one of the following: :values",
        "string": "The :attribute must be a string.",
        "timezone": "The :attribute must be a valid zone.",
        "unique": "The :attribute has already been taken.",
        "uploaded": "The :attribute failed to upload.",
        "url": "The :attribute format is invalid.",
        "uuid": "The :attribute must be a valid UUID.",
        "custom": {
          "attribute-name": {
            "rule-name": "custom-message"
          }
        },
        "attributes": []
      }
    }
  }
}
```

There is no error displayed in console.

Comment: I really doubt `console.log("messages")` outputs anything other than the string `messages`.

Answer (score 0):

You likely need something along the lines of `{{ trans.get('messages.Header') }}`, because `Header` is part of the `messages` array.

The exact syntax may vary; you haven't said *which* translation Vue plugin you're using, so I can't say for certain how it handles the nesting.

Comment: I use this plugin https://github.com/kg-bot/laravel-localization-to-vue. And I tested `{{ trans.get('messages.Header') }}` as well.